# SQL return last 30 records on the same year

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, join, sql-function

In my query I want to return only the records that saved in last 30 days within same year but my query returns all the records that happened in last 30 days from today's month and day regardless of the year. I don't know what the reason
I tried the condition in smaller query and it gives right result.

```
select top 10000 
      cb.billNo , MAX(cb.subCategoryID) subCategory ,
      Max(cb.cateogryID) categoryID ,
      MAX(tracking.date ) trackingDate,

      Max(Station.Code) Dest,Max(cb.picesCount) PieceCount, 
      Max(case when cb.productCount > 1 then 1 else 0 end) isMultiProduct ,
      Max(case when tt.ID = 1 and (cb. subCategoryID = 65 or cb. 
      subCategoryID 
      = 56) then 1 else 0 end) isReceived,
      
from CustomerBillss cb
     join Tracking on cw.billNo = Tracking.billNo
     join trackingtype tt on Tracking.TrackingTypeID = tt.ID
     join Station on cb.destinationStationID = Station.ID

where 
tracking.date > dateadd(dd,-30,cast(getdate() as date))
--(YEAR(tracking.Date) = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND
--tracking.Date >= DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE()))
AND
cb. cateogryID in (1, 3)
AND Tracking.TrackingTypeID not in (8 , 4 ,20) 
AND cb.subCategoryID != 30 or (
   subCategoryID = 30 and cb.DestinationStationID = tracking.StationID)
group by cb.billNo;
```

Comment: In the code you show us the filter on the current year is commented out...

Comment: I guess you've put the last "(" in the wrong place ... at the current position it has no effect ... before "cb.subCategoryID != 30" would make more sense to me

Comment: @Wouter Yes I commented it out because it wasn't working either

Comment: TOP without an order by clause is generally logical nonsense. So what exactly does "last 30 saved" actually mean give the columns you show here or have in your tables? "Saved" and "tracking.date" don't exactly mean the same thing. You say you want "records" but what is the entity that is the primary focus? CustomerBills? Why are you aggregating?

Comment: Ok but like that it's a little difficult to guess what code is not working... anyway PrfctByDsgn is right, you have put a ( at the wrong place.  You will get all the row where  subCategoryID = 30 whatever the date is

Comment: @SMor I used top just for the query to run faster.What I mean by getting the records saved in last 30 days is that in tracking table I have one column for date. It represents at what date this record is inserted. so based on that column

Comment: @SMor by aggregate you mean why I'm using Max in the select statement? It's only because I get this error (invalid select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause) Actually I'm very nob in sql.

Answer (score 0):

Just uncomment the year filter in your select

```
select top 10000 
          cb.billNo , MAX(cb.subCategoryID) subCategory ,
          Max(cb.cateogryID) categoryID ,
          MAX(tracking.date ) trackingDate,
    
          Max(Station.Code) Dest,Max(cb.picesCount) PieceCount, 
          Max(case when cb.productCount > 1 then 1 else 0 end) isMultiProduct ,
          Max(case when tt.ID = 1 and (cb. subCategoryID = 65 or cb. 
          subCategoryID 
          = 56) then 1 else 0 end) isReceived,
          
    from CustomerBillss cb
         join Tracking on cw.billNo = Tracking.billNo
         join trackingtype tt on Tracking.TrackingTypeID = tt.ID
         join Station on cb.destinationStationID = Station.ID
    
    where 
    tracking.date > dateadd(dd,-30,cast(getdate() as date))
    (YEAR(tracking.Date) = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND
    --tracking.Date >= DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE()))
    AND
    cb. cateogryID in (1, 3)
    AND Tracking.TrackingTypeID not in (8 , 4 ,20) 
    AND cb.subCategoryID != 30 or (
       subCategoryID = 30 and cb.DestinationStationID = tracking.StationID)
    group by cb.billNo;
```

Comment: I've tried this before , It gives me records that inserted on these dates 2019-05-11 , 2019-06-30 and other wrong records

Comment: you can use BEETWEEN currentDate and currentDate -30 like this: `WHERE tracking.date BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(d, -30, GETDATE());`

Comment: Still it gives me records with tracking date = 2014-07-14

Comment: Is there an extra AND in the WHERE clause?